# Can someone make this ActionScript to work?

Tags: flash, actionscript, onload

I've made an empty AS 3 .flv document that has one keyframe on position 1 with this action:

```
on(load)

{

    var req:LoadVars = new LoadVars();    
    req.x = "y";  
    req.load("http://localhost/file.php");    
    req.onData = function(src:String) {
        req.x = src;
        req.send("http://localhost/send.php", "_self", "POST"); 
        };
}
```

I'm receiving numerous errors such as the on(load) is invalid. I'm trying to run the code in the beginning of the movie.

Comment: You are getting errors because it is not AS3 : I'm not sure if `on(load)` is AS1 or AS2, but it's definitely not AS3

Comment: And you are sending the req from its `onData` - `onData` is fired only after you have send it and received the response back from server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is AS2, not AS3. on(load) is obsolete in AS3. In AS3, you should use something like this:

```
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

var loader:URLLoader;
var request:URLRequest;

function loadVars():void
{
    request = new URLRequest('your_url.php');

    loader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
    loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);
    loader.load(request);
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    trace("data", e.target.data);
}

function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("IO ERROR", e.text);
}
function onSecError(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("Security ERROR", e.text);
}
```

This code is not tested. Read the online ActionScript 3 Documentation from Adobe for more help!

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 you need to use URLLoader and URLRequest to load external documents into your movie. There is a great example in the live docs provided by Adobe here:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary

I suggest trying that and posting your results back here.